# angular jwt invalid token

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, postman

I have this issue with angular JWT token, which works on my api from Postman but not from the angular call. Request details as follow: [image: screen shot]

I copied the token showed in the response and generate a request through Postman which works.

Any idea why this token could be invalid when sent from angular service?

Postman result below:

[image]

here is the code that produces the token angular side>

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import {
      HttpRequest,
      HttpHandler,
      HttpEvent,
      HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
    //import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Http } from "@angular/http/http";
    import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
    @Injectable()
    export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }
      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
          }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
      }
    }

  public getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authorization header is usually on this format:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

It looks like you're trying to send an entire object. Send only the token field instead.

Comment: This makes sense. Any idea how to do this based on the code shown above?

Comment: Perhaps by changing the return in getToken to `return localStorage.getItem('token').token;`, but that would be a band-aid in my opinion. You can check the content of local storage with Developer Tools (under Application). Check that the content of key: token is a string of type eyJh..., not an entire object. You might be storing the token wrong in local storage when you receive it from the backend.

Comment: When I think of it, I don't think adding .token would help anyway, if the value of local storage are strings. Accessing the token field of the token key in local storage would only work if it was a real object.

Comment: You could call `JSON.parse` on the stored value.

Comment: People claim, the code is working as it is: https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors

Comment: @AluanHaddad: i did JSON.Parse(), would you mind posting complete code?

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp maybe you have an old value saved in localStorage? You could `return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token;`

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Not likely, i copied the value from the request, passed it to Postman and it worked. So that is not the case

Comment: @AluanHaddad, no, with eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

Comment: Right, but what you are sending (in your screenshot) is not that, it is an object.

Comment: It was just basically what @MikaS suggested. But you should not store an object containing the token under the key `"token"`, extract the token and store it or change the key, because it is confusing